# Replace value inside <input> </input> with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input, replace

How to replace the input attribute with jquery? 
The code below:

```
<input class="input-radio" data-checkout-total-shipping="$ 25.00" />
```

I'm using Jquery which gives me a variable "total" 
 Jquery:

```
<script>  
var total = 0;
$(".product__description__property").each(function(d) {
  var value = $(this).text().replace("weight: ", "").replace(" lb", "");
  total += +value; 
});
document.getElementById('total').textContent = total;
</script>
```

I want  to replace whatever is inside " " of data-checkout-total-shipping="25" with total variable from Jquery script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace data attribute with `total` value, you can use:

```
$('.input-radio[data-checkout-total-shipping]').attr('data-checkout-total-shipping', total);
```

So if `total` equals `50` e.g, it will give:

```
<input class="input-radio" data-checkout-total-shipping="50" />
```

If it is not expected behaviour, please elaborate...

Comment: I updated my question.  I want to replace the 25 or whatever is there with my total. I don't have access to the <input /> section. The input is already given I want to replace this on client side so when they submit the form it will send total and not what is already inside the attribute

Comment: So what are you expecting as result? This e.g: `data-checkout-total-shipping="$ 50.00"`. And i think you didn't understood this answer, this is replacing data attribute